# How to create a channel_ID for FCM on an Android device in JavaScript (PWA)?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

In my PWA app some devices do not play sound when receiving a push notification. I'm guessing it's because after Android O, there must be a channel ID, otherwise playing sound won't be allowed.

This is my code of what I send to the FCM server:

```
const toSend ={
        notification:
        {
            title:"Video Call!",
            body:"Video call!",
            click_action: "...",
            sound: "default",
            vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]
        },
        to:othermailandtoken[1]
        };
```

According to this documentation below, I need to add "channel_id". However, all the implementations I found are in Java (Android), but my application is in JavaScript (PWA)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification

> "channel_id    string
>
> The notification's channel id (new in Android O). The app must create
> a channel with this channel ID before any notification with this
> channel ID is received. If you don't send this channel ID in the
> request, or if the channel ID provided has not yet been created by the
> app, FCM uses the channel ID specified in the app manifest."

So how do I create a channel_id that I can send to the application from JavaScript?

Or is there any other way I can make newer android versions play the received `sound: "default"`? Could the problem be something else?

**Edit: ** I found a temporary solution. I go to settings/notifications, and I turn things on manually. Not exactly great, but better than nothing for now.

Comment: Having the same issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862991/progressive-web-app-pwa-not-able-to-make-push-notifications-pop-up-on-screen-o. Still no answer for 3 months...

Comment: I see. the only workaround I found so far is just basically turning things on manually in settings/notifications/appname. It's good enough for me for a prototype at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use [`AndroidNotification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification), which offers the property `channel_id`.

However, this only seems to be available on the REST API - but JS can access that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's for sending notifications to native Android apps, not PWAs. I don't think it's applicable here.